# Sigo recibiendo Response 503 cuando hago requests.get con URL

Tags: python, scraping, requests, headers

Muy buenas, llevo un rato recibiendo <Response [503]> haga lo que haga con esta URL, ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
import requests
  
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
  'Referer': 'https://google.com/',
  'DNT': '1',
}

proxies = {
  "http": None,
  "https": None,
}

url = 'https://www.wildfooduk.com/mushroom-guide/?mushroom_type=edible'
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, proxies = proxies)

r
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo,

Comment: Esta usando Cloudflare y seguramente se han dado cuenta de tus intentos y ya no te dejan pasar.  A mi me han dejado con wget, pero tampoco he insistido demasiado.

Comment: ¿Existe alguna manera de conseguir la request con Cloudfare?

Comment: Supongo, crea una pregunta específica para ello y a ver que te dicen